# how to get conversion tracking code in bing?

Tags: advertising, bing-webmaster-tools, microsoft

https://about.ads.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/training/universal-event-tracking says "*To get started, click the **Campaigns** page, and then on the left pane, click **Conversion Tracking***":

[image]

Only problem: I'm not seeing a "Conversion Tracking" link when I click on "Campaigns":

[image]

If I do Ctrl + F I get no results back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a link: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Adding-Microsoft-Advertising-Conversion-Tracking on how to get the conversion tracking code in Bing. hope it helps you.

Comment: So you have to click on Tools. Ugh. Anyway, that link helps - thanks! That said, you should probably include the relevant parts of the answer in your post. As is your post is liable to be flagged for deletion, in spite of containing the answer, since it's a link only answer.